# How to restrict app installation on devices which don't have 4K camera?

Tags: android, camera, android-manifest, restrictions

I'm writing application which should be installed only on devices with supported 4K camera. How I could add that restriction

Comment: Are there few enough such devices you could manually restrict it to only those known to have a 4K camera?  It risks excluding compatible devices, is labor intensive, and won't scale in the future but it could work.  Sort of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the present time Android doesn't have any way to implement such restriction. App installation filters are set via the [uses-feature](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element) manifest element tag, which as you can see in the documentation doesn't have a way to filter by video resolutions. If you really need such constrain, then you are left with a very rough way to help you, which is to ensure the store description highlights this requirement well, maybe even to do an icon design that may hint on this limitation, and probably to show a message when the app starts if detected no 4K support. A very ugly way to do it, but right now would be the only way.